# Позвонить из приложения

Tags: android

Нужно вызвать звонилку из приложения с заранее указанным номером.
Использую код:

```
String number = "tel:+7123456789";
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(number));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Последняя строчка подсвечивается красным. Как поправить?
И какая разметка нужна в лайаоте, чтобы отображать кнопку со звонком?

Comment: Нужно поставить курсор на красный балун в линейке слева и прочитать сообщение об ошибке. Для кнопки со звонком можете использовать любую разметку, которая вам нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity()` является методом класса `Activity`, то есть вам нужен экземпляр этого класса - если совсем по простому нужна переменная с типом `Activity`, в частном случае это может быть и `this`, если запуск происходит внутри `Activity`:

```
Activity myActivity;
//бла-бла
String number = "tel:+7123456789";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(number));
myActivity.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Чтобы выделить в виде разметки можно просто использовать:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myId"
android:text="tel:+7123456789"
android:autolink="phone"/>
```